# Why is "boot-repair" listed twice in the ubuntu documentation?

Tags: boot-repair

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm going through the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Can someone explain why the command `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair` lists "boot-repair" twice?

[image: Seen here in this image.]

Comment: Obviously because `boot-repair` is twice as important as the other commands _(joke)_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last line contains two commands.

The first part installs `boot-repair`.  (`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`)

The "&&" characters is a delimiter like ";" is, however its conditional on success, ie. the command following it is only to be run IF the first command had no errors.

The 'second' `boot-repair` is the one that runs it.

Comment: If you used a ";" and the install command worked; the result would be the same as it'd install, then run.  If however the install failed you'd get errors for the install failing, followed by more errors as `boot-repair` couldn't be found...  The && conditional parameters reduces the errors (if they occur) as they [errors] can scare users  (what did i do wrong? did i break it?..)

Comment: oh of course, that makes sense. Thank you. I was thinking that it was trying to install it twice.